# Windows Band Tile GeoFencing

Tags: microsoft-band

We are going to be developing Tiles for the Microsoft Band 2. Is there anyway to Geo-Fence certain Tiles based on GPS that are created for business use so they only work within the confines of the company area?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "work within the confine of the company area".  You cannot run code on the Band itself (only read from or push to the Band via an application running on your mobile device), so you cannot prevent the user from arbitrarily opening a Tile if it's present on the Band.  There are also no geo-fencing features related to Tiles on the Band.

If you don't want custom buttons within a Tile to function when outside of a given region--that's easy.  Button press events are sent to and handled by the application on the mobile device and can simply be ignored if the user is outside that region.

If you don't want the user to see any content in the Tile outside of a given region, you may be able to use the Tile opened events to give your application an opportunity to clear the content of the Tile if the mobile device is outside that region (and then to re-send it if inside that range).  Still, pushing content to the Band over a Bluetooth takes time so the user may still have the opportunity to see the content before it's cleared/updated.  Even if were fast, you can only connect to the Band when both Bluetooth is enabled and the Band is within range of the mobile device.  If the user were to turn off Bluetooth on the Band or just step far enough away from the mobile device, the user will be able to see all existing content within the Tile.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. When talking about the company area I wanted to put a geo-fence as a 1000m boundary circumference around the center point in the Plant. The reason is that we want the employees to enjoy these bands at home and not have to deal with work tiles  at home but have to see them when they are at the office.